# Python PyMongo / Displaying Output as a plain String

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I have a quick question: I have a MongoDB Database with a collection of dummy data. I used the follwoing code to display all documents within my collection (in this case FlightNo and Terminal):

```
def getAllFlights():
        for x in flightsCol.find({}, {"_id": 0, "number": 1, "terminal": 1}):
        print(x)
```

This works pretty good and the Output looks like that:

```
{'number': 'XXA54', 'terminal': 'O2'}
{'number': 'LH587', 'terminal': 'PO'}
{'number': 'KLH552', 'terminal': 'LO556'}
{'number': 'LO552', 'terminal': 'H1'}
{'number': 'HHG565', 'terminal': 'H1'}
{'number': 'TRE223', 'terminal': 'LK1'}
{'number': 'JUZ556', 'terminal': 'KL234'}
```

> **My question now:**
>   How can I display the output as plain text like:

XXA54 O2

**Thank you for your help!**

Michele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print each part of the returned dictionary:

```
def getAllFlights():
    for x in flightsCol.find({}, {"_id": 0, "number": 1, "terminal": 1}):
        print(x["number"],x["terminal"])
```